# How do I get JSX as a string?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, reactjs

I'd like to write a higher order component, let's say `AddMarkup`, that has a single child. It should render the child along with the code that generates it. For example:

```
<AddMarkup>
  <MyButton color="red">
    Red Button
  </MyButton>
</AddMarkup>
```

should result in something like this:

```
<div>
  <button style={{ color: 'red' }}>    /* Assume that MyButton is implemented this way */
    Red Button
  </button>
  <pre>
    <MyButton color="red">
      Red Button
    </MyButton>
  </pre>
</div>
```

I'm struggling with the `<pre>` bit. Is there a way to grab the original JSX as a string (so I could put it in the `<pre>` tag)? Is there any Babel or Webpack magic that I can apply?

Comment: That's a tricky one ! I'm not sure there is a simple solution to 'reverse' transpile from the result of a React element to its JSX string representation. Maybe you could find some inspiration on React dev tools repo to see how they display the jsx in console, maybe in the [Node.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/frontend/Node.js) file ?

Comment: Maybe [jsx-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-to-string) could be hooked up in some weird way through a Babel plugin. You would need to define some convention (`props.childrenAsString`?) and generate code matching that in Babel while processing it through **jsx-to-string**. After this your code would be married with a custom Babel plugin which isn't particularly cool.

Comment: @bebraw Yeah, `jsx-to-string` is probably a good start. Feel free to post it as an answer ;)

Comment: Posted as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the best way to solve this is to write a custom Babel plugin that relies on [jsx-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-to-string) to deal with the conversion. You'll need to write code that will inject the code as a string through some predefined prop (plugin setting) like `childrenAsString`.

Although this would work, it would also tie your code to Babel. Still, if you need it and you are happy with the gotcha, it could be worth a go.